# Json jolt transformation from attributes to key value pair

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

Im trying to transform something like this:

```
{

  "Id":"123",

  "Att1":"value1",

  "Att2":"value2",

  ...

  "Attn":"valuen"

}
```

To:

```
{ 

  "Id":"123",

  "AttJson": "{\\"Att1\\":\\"Value1\\",\\"Att2\\":\\"Value2\\",...,\\"Attn\\":\\"Valuen\\"}"

}
```

So basically keep the id as is but wrap remaining attributes in one json sting that will be a value of one key. Is this possible? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the one which you are looking for(as per my understanding) is possible. Below is the utlity for the same.

It'll take `data` as input and keep the `Id` as is.

```js
let data = {
  Id: '123',
  Att1: 'value1',
  Att2: 'value2',
  Attn: 'valuen',
};

const formatJSON = (data) => {
  const dataCopy = { ...data
  };
  const idVal = dataCopy.Id;
  delete dataCopy.Id;
  return {
    Id: idVal,
    AttJson: JSON.stringify(dataCopy)
  }
}

console.log(formatJSON(data))
console.log(data)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nithish, i meant to say doing this using jolt schema with spec like shift, modify-overwrite-beta...etc. im doing this for Nifi Jolt transformation processor.